# Parent-Child navigation across multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

please bear with me for the explanation, it's necessary.

**System background:**
I am creating a parent->child navigation system for the backend of a CMS. 
I build URLs like so: `[domain.ext]/[moduleName]/[objectName]/[actionName]/[ID #1]/[ID #2]`.

The URL explained (e.g. `example.com/PageManagement/Page/Modify/7/13`):

- ***moduleName***: the name of the module the object belongs to (e.g. "PageManagement")
- ***objectName***: the name of the object (e.g. "Page")
- ***actionName***: the name of the action (e.g. "Modify")
- ***ID #1***: *either* the ID of the record the action is being performed on, ***or*** the ID of the object's parent
- ***ID #2***: the ID of the record the action is being performed on, *but only if ID #1 is filled with a parent ID*

Navigation happens by parsing the URL for its components, reducing the names to system IDs etc., and then retrieving the fields and data which are to be displayed on the page.
To ensure the URL remains readable and logically understandable I don't add multiple layers of parent ID's to the URL, but rather keep the last few parent IDs in the PHP `$_SESSION` array, so I can determine on navigation whether a different parent ID has to be added.

**Example:** image we have the objects `Page->Extension->Field`, which are all in the module `PageManagement` and parented from left to right. Now let's say we have a Page with ID 2, an Extension with ID 8, and a Field with ID 17. The URL for editing the Field would be `example.com/PageManagement/Field/Modify/8/17`, because we are editing Field 17, which has Extension 8 as parent. The URL for editing the Extension would be `example.com/PageManagement/Extension/Modify/2/8`, because we are editing Extension 8, which has Page 2 as parent. Editing the Page would simply be `example.com/PageManagement/Page/Modify/2`, because it has no parent.

**Problem:**
Now, all of this works perfectly. **However,** if multiple tabs are opened they share the same `$_SESSION`, so navigating in one tab can throw off the parent history for the other tab. It still goes right in ***almost*** all cases, but the fact I *can* cause it is bad (since someone can be adding/deleting/editing data without knowing they are actually in the wrong parent list).

**What I need:** I need a way, with each request, to determine from which tab it came, most likely by generating some form of UID per tab and sending that with each request. My system can then store the navigation history per tab, instead of per session.

**Considered solutions**

- Generating a UID per page session, and storing this in the `Window.sessionStorage` (which gets reset for each new window/tab). This would allow me to generate one if none is set yet (so a new tab), and thus have a different one stored (and remembered) per page session.

  - ***Problem:*** I don't know how I can get that UID sent to the server with each request. Session cookies seem to be shared between all tabs (makes sense since they share a session).
- Generating a UID per page session, and appending that to the URL as a query string.

  - ***Problem:*** I might as well not have nice URLs, and if someone (accidentally) edits/removes it, it will still not work. Also, copy/pasting the URL will be a problem.
- Generating a UID per page session, and prepending that to the URL before the `moduleName`.

  - ***Problem:*** It is still visible/editable/removable, and if they do it will still not work. Also, copy/pasting the URL will be a problem.

If anyone can solve the problems mentioned for the solutions above, or come up with a completely new solution, that would be amazing.
Obviously I'd prefer make as few changes as possible to how the URL system works, but if that is the only solution, so be it...

Comment: Your URLs are fundamentaly wrong. Instead of relying on server context, a request composed of URL and BODY should contain all the information needed to perform an operation. Server context should be used for validation/authorization, no more.

Comment: @Amit So what you are basically saying is that I **should** have all the parent IDs in the URL, no matter how many there may be? And would you be more inclined toward `example.com/PageManagement/Field/Modify/2/8/17` (so what I already have, just all the parents added), or would you prefer `example.com/PageManagement/Page/2/Extension/8/Field/17/Modify` (completely restructured to have each object name and ID, and the action at the end)?

Comment: I add to the fact that the http request alone (url, headers, body) should describe the action. I think that using urls like `example.com/PageManagement/Page/2/Extension/8/Field/17/Modify` are self-explanatory, and easy to create.

Comment: yup, just put everything in the URL. There are some great benefits in doing this, such as your users being able to bookmark a page with a given state.

Comment: Alright, my course of action seems to be decided then. @Amit if you add an answer similar to your comment I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a basic flaw in your request design that's causing you all the trouble.
A system should strive to include all relevant information within a single request whenever possible. In your case, that means ditching the mechanism that "remembers" earlier requests (state..) in the `$_SESSION` and instead pass all the information in the request. It can be in the URL ("address" and/or query string), the headers when appropriate (Usually using cookies. Probably inappropriate in this case) or body (same way as POSTed forms pass the payload).

There are numerous reasons to choose this path, to name a few:

1. Improve logging.
2. Ease debugging.
3. Enable simple, URL based linking (when using only the URL for requests).
4. Reduce risk of incorrect caching (local or remote).
5. Support multiple "simultaneous" requests -> Will help overcome current issue :-)

As always, no rule goes without exceptions. In this case, the most common piece of information that is NOT suitable to be included in each request is authentication information (username, password, etc...)

To summarize, you should strongly consider reconstructing your requests such that all required information is available.